# How to I change my CSS according to JSON data value?

Tags: css, angularjs, json, twitter-bootstrap

Suppose one of my keys has value Green/Red and I want to show bootstrap `btn-success` when its value is green and `btn-danger` when its red.

Comment: Can you paste your JSON format?

Comment: See this example http://jsfiddle.net/75m7e/2527/

Comment: Thanks this worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update `ng-class`

```
<div ng:controller="CartForm">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat='country in countries'><a class="btn" ng-class="{'btn-primary': country.color == 'green', 'btn-danger': country.color == 'red'}" href="">{{country.name}} - {{country.population}}</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

and delete `appliedClass` function

Working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/75m7e/2529/)

Comment: You can add more classes in future

Comment: When I vote up your answer it increments by 1 and then changes back. Can somebody explain me why.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for [ng-class](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass). You can use the following synthax:

```
<p ng-class="condition ? 'classIfTrue' : 'classIfFalse'">Foo</p>
```

In your case, it would be something like:

```
<p ng-class="myVariable ? 'btn-success' : 'btn-danger'">Foo</p>
```

As you did not provide a code sample, here is how it works with an example:

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('MyCtrl', function() {
    this.valueSuccess = false;
    this.valueDanger = true;
});
```

```css
.danger { background-color: red; }
.success { background-color: green; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<section ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl as vm">
    <p ng-class="vm.valueSuccess ? 'danger' : 'success'"> {{vm.valueSuccess}}</p>
    <p ng-class="vm.valueDanger ? 'danger' : 'success'">{{vm.valueDanger}}</p>
  </div>
</section>
```